# PHP function for handling MySQL infinite & nested queries

Tags: php, mysqli, nested

I've been asked by my colleague to make a *PHP* function to plug into our web application to handle an infinite amount of nested (looped) queries to make our lives much easier, without being worried about loosing the current and/or previous results.

Here is the code I came up after minutes, and it seems that it works fine, however I still have these questions:

1. Am I re-inventing the [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) function?
2. Is it smart to handling these nested queries in this way?
3. What could be pros and cons of using the following approach?

The actual function:

```
function qn($query) {
    global $db;
    $rand_var = 'r' . mktime() . mt_rand();
    $$rand_var = $db->query($query);
    return $$rand_var;
}
```

and in action:

```
if (($db instanceof mysqli) != true) {
   $db = new mysqli(DB_ADDRESS, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
}

$a = qn('SELECT DISTINCT ***');

while ($row_a = $a->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do some stuff
    $b = qn('SELECT ***' . $row_a['foo']);
    while ($row_b = $b->fetch_assoc()) {
        $c = qn('SELECT COUNT(id)' . $row_b['bar']);
        // keep going ...
    }
}
```

**Note:** SQL queries are sample.

Comment: One has to say it: If you even need a "solution to handle nested queries" you probably have a much more severe problem in your data model.

Comment: Recursion is the answer.

Comment: Why not just do `return $db->query($query);`?  Which to assign to local variable with unique name first?

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov good point! why do i need that?!

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig Well, you're right, however sometimes you are not allowed to change the database scheme! what you can do is to query that somehow, and nothing more!

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov you're 100% right! could you please post your comment as answer, so I can choose that, thanks.

Comment: @Mahdi Reposted as answer in slightly different form.  Just didn't thought that problem was that easy.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov yeap, the whole idea of the function was to generating a random and unique variable to store the results, which you just spot that is clearly the most useless thing in the world! I can't believe that I was so stupid to writing such a function!

Comment: @Mahdi BTW, when you need to generate unique names for something, you better user incrementing counter rather than random number, because this is faster, simpler and guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov yeap, you're right again. I always love to do these kind of micro optimisations. good point! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
$rand_var = 'r' . mktime() . mt_rand();
$$rand_var = $db->query($query);
return $$rand_var;
```

could be simplified to

```
return $db->query($query);
```

Cause it just stores query result in local variable with unique name before returning it.  This does not make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: [SafeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) is what you're looking for and many, many more!

```
if (!($db instanceof safemysql)) {
   $db = new safemysql(...);
}

$a = $db->getCol('SELECT DISTINCT ***');
foreach ($a as $foo) {
    // do some stuff
    $b = $db->getAll('SELECT ***', $foo);
    foreach ($b as $row_b) {
        $c = $db->getOne(('SELECT COUNT(id)', $row_b['bar']);
         // keep going ...
    }
}
```

To answer your question

> Am I re-inventing the mysqli_prepare function?

Definitely NO.
You're preparing nothing.

> Is it smart to handling these nested queries in this way?

No. The probability of collision is pretty high. At least use microtime instead of mktime.

> What could be pros and cons of using the following approach?

There a lot of cons

- no error handling
- no placeholders support
- messy code
- whole `qn()` function being useless. you can use $db->query() alone instead.

Also,  **Till Helge Helwig** is absolutely right: all nested queries can (and should) be replaced with single query with join (and grouping).